# detecting a click inside a hexagon drawn using canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, path-2d

I'm working on a certain layout where I need to draw a hexagon which needs to be clickable. I'm using the Path2D construct and isPointInPath function. I'm constructing an animation where a number of hexagons is created and then each moved to a certain position. After the movement is done, I am attaching onclick event handlers to certain hexagons. However there is weird behaviour.

Some initialized variables

```
const COLOR_DARK = "#73b6c6";
const COLOR_LIGHT = "#c3dadd";
const COLOR_PRIMARY = "#39a4c9";

const TYPE_PRIMARY = 'primary';

let hexagons = [];
```

Below is the function which draws the hexagons.

```
function drawHex(ctx, x, y, hexProps, stroke, color) {

    let myPath = new Path2D();

    myPath.moveTo(x + hexProps.width*0.5, y);
    myPath.lineTo(x, y + hexProps.height*hexProps.facShort);
    myPath.lineTo(x, y + hexProps.height*hexProps.facLong);
    myPath.lineTo(x + hexProps.width*0.5, y + hexProps.height);
    myPath.lineTo(x + hexProps.width, y + hexProps.height*hexProps.facLong);
    myPath.lineTo(x + hexProps.width, y + hexProps.height*hexProps.facShort);
    myPath.lineTo(x + hexProps.width*0.5, y);
    myPath.closePath();

    if (stroke){
        ctx.strokeStyle = color;
        ctx.stroke(myPath);
    } else {
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fill(myPath);
    }

    return myPath;
}
```

This function populates the hexagon array

```
function populateLeftHex(canvasWidth, canvasHeight, hexProps) {

const startX = canvasWidth / 2;
const startY = canvasHeight / 2;
const baseLeft = canvasWidth * 0.05;

for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    let hexNumber = (i % 4 == 0)? 2: 1;

    for(let j = 0; j < hexNumber; j++){
        hexagons.push({
            startX: startX,
            startY: startY,
            endX: baseLeft + (2 * j) + ((i % 2 == 0)? (hexProps.width * j) : (hexProps.width/2)),
            endY: ((i + 1) * hexProps.height) - ((i) * hexProps.height * hexProps.facShort)  + (i* 2),
            stroke: true,
            color: ( i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 == 0)? COLOR_DARK : COLOR_LIGHT,
            type: TYPE_PRIMARY
        });
    }
}
```

}

And here is where Im calling the isPointInPath function.

```
   window.onload = function (){
const c = document.getElementById('canvas');

const canvasWidth = c.width = window.innerWidth,
    canvasHeight = c.height = window.innerHeight,
    ctx = c.getContext('2d');

window.requestAnimFrame = (function (callback) {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function (callback) {
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
})();

console.log(canvasWidth);

let hexProps = {
  width: canvasWidth * 0.075,
    get height () {
      return this.width/Math.sqrt(3) + (1.5)*(this.width/Math.sqrt(2)/2);
    } ,
    facShort: 0.225,
    get facLong () {
      return 1 - this.facShort;
    }
};


populateLeftHex(canvasWidth, canvasHeight, hexProps);

let pct = 0;
const fps = 200;

animate();


function animate () {

    setTimeout(function () {
    // increment pct towards 100%
    pct += .03;

    // if we're not done, request another animation frame
    if (pct < 1.00) {
        requestAnimFrame(animate);
    } else { //if pct is no longer less than 1.00, then the movement animation is over.
        hexagons.forEach(function (hex) {
            if(hex.type === TYPE_PRIMARY) {

                console.info(hex.path);


                c.onclick = function(e) {

                    let x = e.clientX - c.offsetLeft,
                        y = e.clientY - c.offsetTop;
                    console.info(ctx.isPointInPath(hex.path, (e.clientX - c.offsetLeft), (e.clientY - c.offsetTop) ));
                };
            }
        })
    }

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

        // draw all hexagons
        for ( let i = 0; i < hexagons.length; i++) {

            // get reference to next shape
            let hex = hexagons[i];

            // note: dx/dy are fixed values
            // they could be put in the shape object for efficiency
            let dx = hex.endX - hex.startX;
            let dy = hex.endY - hex.startY;
            let nextX = hex.startX + dx * pct;
            let nextY = hex.startY + dy * pct;
            hex = hexagons[i];
            ctx.fillStyle = hex.color;
            hex.path = drawHex(ctx, nextX, nextY, hexProps, hex.stroke, hex.color);


        }

    }, 1000 / fps);
}
```

Can you help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Maybe I misunderstood how Path2D works? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are drawing multiple paths (hexagons) correct?  I don't think this is the best approach.  `isPointInPath()` will only tell you if a point is in the current path.  You'll have to check the point while you are drawing.  The way your code works now, it will only check if the click was in the last hexagon drawn.  At least, that is how I am understanding the documentation.

Comment: It's true, the drawHex function draws one hexagon. But im calling it many times. There is a weird behavior happening now... I'm constructing a complex animation .. I'll update the question

Answer (score 0):

Had to do a bit of work to build a test page as your example is incomplete, but this is working for me - though my hexagon is concave...

```js
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");

var hexProps = {width:100, height:100, facShort:-2, facLong:10};

var hexagons = [];

 function drawHex(ctx, x, y, hexProps, stroke, color) {

     let myPath = new Path2D();

     myPath.moveTo(x + hexProps.width*0.5, y);
     myPath.lineTo(x, y + hexProps.height*hexProps.facShort);
     myPath.lineTo(x, y + hexProps.height*hexProps.facLong);
     myPath.lineTo(x + hexProps.width*0.5, y + hexProps.height);
     myPath.lineTo(x + hexProps.width, y + hexProps.height*hexProps.facLong);
     myPath.lineTo(x + hexProps.width, y + hexProps.height*hexProps.facShort);
     myPath.lineTo(x + hexProps.width*0.5, y);
     myPath.closePath();

     if (stroke){
         ctx.strokeStyle = color;
         ctx.stroke(myPath);
     } else {
         ctx.fillStyle = color;
         ctx.fill(myPath);
     }

     return myPath;
 }

hexagons.push({type:0, path:drawHex(ctx,100,100,hexProps,false,"#0f0")});

   hexagons.forEach(function (hex) {
            if(hex.type === 0) {

                console.info(hex.path);


                myCanvas.onclick = function(e) {

                    let x = e.clientX - myCanvas.offsetLeft,
                        y = e.clientY - myCanvas.offsetTop;
                    console.info(x,y);
                    console.info(ctx.isPointInPath(hex.path, (e.clientX - 
 myCanvas.offsetLeft), (e.clientY - myCanvas.offsetTop) ));

                };
            }
        })
```

```html
<canvas width=500 height=500 id=myCanvas style='border:1px solid red'></canvas>
```

Test clicks give true and false where expected:

```
test.htm:48 165 168
test.htm:49 true
test.htm:48 151 336
test.htm:49 false
test.htm:48 124 314
test.htm:49 true
test.htm:48 87 311
test.htm:49 false
```